# Understanding HashMap - Inserting data into HashMap

Tags: android, hashmap

[EDIT]: HashMap stores a reference to ArrayList, NOT a copy. So, creating a new instance of ArrayList is necessary for inserting new set of items.

---

I am having trouble understanding how HashMap works. Here is what I am doing..

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> data = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> dataValues;
```

somewhere in the code.. adding dummy data..

```
dataValues = new ArrayList<String>();
dataValues.clear();

dataValues.add("Product - Nike : 20% OFF just today");
dataValues.add("Product - Adidas : 30% OFF on Shoes");
dataValues.add("Product - Puma : 40% OFF Weekend Sale");
dataValues.add("Product - Zapper : 50% OFF Clearence Sale");
data.put(1, dataValues);

dataValues.clear();

dataValues
        .add("Product - Dining Table : FLAT 50% OFF on all dining tables - Just for today");
dataValues
        .add("Product - Chairs : New Arrival - SOFA cum CHAIR convertible");
dataValues.add("Product - Organisers : Buy 1 Get one Free");
dataValues
        .add("Product - Decorative Pillows : New Arrival - Transformers 4 theme");
data.put(2, dataValues);

dataValues.clear();

dataValues
        .add("Product - Ice Cream Bonanza : Get 25% more on all IceCreams");
dataValues
        .add("Product - Vanilla : Get 50% extra in the next one hour");
dataValues
        .add("Product - Butterscoth : Get 100% extra in the next 15 mins");
dataValues
        .add("Product - Pista : Get Family pack icecream free if you visit our store in the next 5 mins");
data.put(3, dataValues);

dataValues.clear();

dataValues
        .add("Product - Skaters Delight : Get skating set for FLAT 50% OFF");
dataValues
        .add("Product - Cricket Mania : Get Cricketing gear for 25% OFF");
dataValues
        .add("Product - Football Fever : Buy any shoe and get a Football Free");
dataValues.add("Product - Rugby : Kill yourself with a Rugby armour");
data.put(4, dataValues);

dataValues.clear();
```

Now somewhere else.. i am trying to retrieve the values from the List, with key = 1.

```
List<String> dataValue = new ArrayList<String>();
dataValue = data.get(1);
```

when i try to get the size of dataValue using dataValue.size(), i get the size as 0.

if i don't clear the dataValues list, after every data.put() statement in the above code, then its working just fine. I get a non-zero value for dataValue.size()

My question is, when i do, data.put(1, dataValues), does it keep reference to dataValues in the HashMap, and hence i am getting 0 for size, as i am clearing it in the next step? If so, i have to create a List for every set of values that I want to insert into HashMap? or is there a way i can do it with a single List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `dataValues.clear();`,

you should create every time a new instance of

```
dataValues = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks.. Can you explain me why should i be creating a new instance instead of using the old one?

Comment: the HashMap stores a reference to the ArrayList, it does not create new copy of the object you provide sa paratmer

Comment: you are welcome. I would like to suggest you a nice book, that you can use as reference, it called *thinking in java*

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you put the same object but with different key each time. So when you call `clear()` all values in `HashMap` are cleared. Try to create a new object for each value. Keep in mind, that `List<String> dataValues` just stores reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. So in java and many other programming languages, dynamically created objects are stored on the heap, so when you

```
dataValues.clear()
```

you are still referencing the same list with the same items. So you could set

```
dataValues = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This has less to do with Android, but ties into more important concepts in computer science. You should definitely dive into data structures!

Answer (score -1):

The Best way to insert data into HashMap of HashMap in java is:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myMap = new  HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

innerMap.put("Name", "John");

innerMap.put("Age", "25");

myMap.put("1", innerMap);

//Now don't erase the data of innerMap otherwise it will also removed from myMap

innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

innerMap.put("Name", "Rock");

innerMap.put("Age", "26");

myMap.put("2", innerMap);
```

I hope you will find this helpful!